# IIS 8 Mod_Rewrite activation

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite

I made a site in PHP, using wamp server. I used also mod_rewrite. Now, I placed my site on my Windows Server 2012 where is installed IIS 8.0. But here, mod_rewrite doesn't work anymore.

I found something like mod_rewrite for IIS, named IIS Url Rewrite 2.0, downloaded and installed, but I'm absolutely newbie on Windows Server, and I don't know where to find settings to enable mod_rewrite support.

Rewrite rules are very simple, like that

```
RewriteRule ^home/$ /index.php
```

Here is the site address on the web http://cim.sswdesign.pw

edit:

Can anyone tell me how to enable rewriting support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS7 and above has it's own URL rewrite module.

Rules go in web.config (rather than .htaccess).  You can add them there yourself manually, or you can use the "wizard" in IIS manager.

http://www.surfingsuccess.com/asp/iis-url-rewrite.html

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thanks for good answer, but I've done everything already, and web.conf file I've filled using Sublime Text 2 with it's fantastic multiple replacing :)